# Prove uniqueness of solution to $x^2 y = x - y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

So for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I have to prove that a unique $y \in \mathbb{R}$ exists such that $x^2 y = x - y$.

What I did was this:

I showed that such a $y$ exists by performing algebra to get $y = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$. Then by noting that $x^2 + 1 \ne 0$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$ since real numbers are closed under non-zero division. Afterwards I assumed another value $z$ that has the property $x^2z = x - z$. Performing the same process I get $z = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$ which is the same value as $y$. Therefore $y=z$ and that the value of $y$ is unique.

Is this a sound proof or not? Anything wrong with it?

Comment: I think that is fine!

Comment: Do I have to add that $y \ne z$ when I assumed $z$?

Comment: There is no need for that statement. It is sufficient to prove that for any other $z$ satisfying $x^2z = x-z$, $y=z$. If you start with $y\neq z$, then the above proves that $y=z$, which then you would address as a contradiction, only a slight change in the method of solving. You have caught the problem by the throat, and probably strangled it completely. There's nothing more to add in the answer. It's excellent.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. This looks solid!

Comment: Okay thanks! @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг if you would be so kind tho to add an answer so that this question wouldn't be unanswered.